# Add widget to Qsqlquerymodel

Tags: qt, pyqt

I want to add a column of checkboxes to a Qsqlquerymodel. The checkboxes are not linked to the data base. Using delegates seems much to low level for what I am trying to do.

The code I would like to use would be based on (PyQt) :

```
model = QtSql.QSqlQueryModel()

model.insertColumn(2) #checkbox column

checkboxes = list() #Used later to check checkboxe state
for i in range(0, model.rowCount()):
    checkboxes.append((i, QtGui.QCheckBox())) #store row and checkbox in list
    model.addWidget(i, 2, checkboxes[-1][1]) #addWidget in row(i), col(2) does not exist :(
```

- Is it possible not to use delegates so the code is simpler?
- Should I use layouts and not include the checkboxes in the model?
- Am I missing a simple solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I mangaed by subclassing QsqlQueryModel following [Sibylle Koczian](http://www.mail-archive.com/pyqt@riverbankcomputing.com/msg18504.html) work.

```
class CheckboxSqlModel(QtSql.QSqlQueryModel):
    def __init__(self, column):
        super(CheckboxSqlModel, self).__init__()
        self.column = column
        self.checkboxes = list() #List of checkbox states
        self.first = list() #Used to initialize checkboxes

    #Make column editable
    def flags(self, index):
        flags = QtSql.QSqlQueryModel.flags(self, index)
        if index.column() == self.column:
            flags |= QtCore.Qt.ItemIsUserCheckable
        return flags

    def data(self, index, role=QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole):
        row = index.row()
        if index.column() == self.column and role == QtCore.Qt.CheckStateRole:
            #Used to initialize
            if row not in self.first :
                index = self.createIndex(row, self.column)
                self.first.append(row)
                self.checkboxes.append(False)
                return QtCore.Qt.Unchecked
            #if checked
            elif self.checkboxes[row]:
                return QtCore.Qt.Checked
            else:
                return QtCore.Qt.Unchecked
        else:
            return QtSql.QSqlQueryModel.data(self, index, role)

    def setData(self, index, value, role=QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole):
        row = index.row()
        if index.column() == self.column and role == QtCore.Qt.CheckStateRole:
            if value.toBool():
                self.checkboxes[row] = True
            else:
                self.checkboxes[row] = False
            self.dataChanged.emit(index, index)
            return True
        else:
            return False
```